# $compile service in angular returns an array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, compilation

I am trying to compile a static DOM against scope using the following code

```
(function(angular) {
  var app = angular.module("directiveModule1",[]);
  app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.UserName = "afh";
  }]);
  app.directive("linkFuncDirective",['$compile', function($compile) {
return {
  link: function(scope, element, attrs,controller) {
    var markUp = "<input type = 'text' ng-model ='UserName'/>{{UserName}}</br>";
    var linkFunc = $compile(markUp);
    var content = linkFunc(scope);
    angular.element(element).html(content);
    //angular.element(element).html($compile(markUp)(scope));
  }
};
 }]);
})(window.angular);
```

and my html is below

```
 <html>

<head>

  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.0-beta.5"        src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="directiveWithLinkFunction.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-App="directiveModule1">

  <div ng-controller="testController">
    <div link-func-directive></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

and I get the following o/p

```
[[object HTMLInputElement], [object HTMLSpanElement], [object HTMLBRElement]]
```

Trying to understand what was written wrong in code, any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind html is having `[[object HTMLInputElement], [object HTMLSpanElement], [object HTMLBRElement]]` on view is, You have compiled one line of html using `$compile` service which returns below as compiled DOM

```
<input type="text" ng-model="UserName">
<span class="ng-binding ng-scope"></span>
<br class="ng-scope">
```

So basically it has 3 elements, 1st one is input element, 2nd is span & 3rd is `br` break tag. So when you try to add it as HTML to page using `.html` method, `jQLite` internally takes that object and apply `.toString()` method to making sure it should accept the string. That's the reason why you are getting `[Object...]` in the output.

---

Basically your problem is you are assigning compiled angular DOM `html` content to the directive element html, which wouldn't make sense.

It should be `.append` function instead of `.html` as angular compiled DOM will get injected will have binding enabled.

```
element.append(content); //would append the DOM with angular compiled DOM.
```

Comment: Appreciate the detailed explanation. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to compile that in the first place ? You can use a simple template for that.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is a little bit mess. Try to clean up first.

1. give a restrict property to your directive
2. if you don't have a required field then you don't need a `controller` parameter
3. Why don't you just simple use a template for your directive

Comment: I know that I can pretty much use a template. Just so you understand, I am not simply trying to make this directive work rather trying to experiment and learn compile in detail.